# AngularJS does not work with ASP.Net MVC Partial View loaded from clicking on a @Ajax.ActionLink()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to use AngularJS with ASP.Net MVC. My problem is that AngularJS is not working in the rendered view calling from `@Ajax.actionLink()`. Here is the sample code i have tried. I have a ASP.Net MVC controller `index()` which is follows:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The index View which contains the `@Ajax.ActionLink`:

```
<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Show Log", "ShowLog", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "WorkArea"})
</div>
<div id="WorkArea"></div>
<script src="~/App_Content/JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App_Content/JS/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

The ShowLog controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowLog()
{
    return View();
}
```

Here's the main part of the `ShowLog()` View where I try to add AngularJS:

```
<script src="~/App_Content/JS/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App_Content/JS/Practical/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/App_Content/JS/Practical/MainController.js"></script>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h3>Log View</h3>
<div ng-app="AgApp">
    <div ng-controller="PostController">
        <div>{{MessageHeading}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the index file the link `Show Log` is shown. When I click on it the view `ShowLog` has rendered in the workarea as expected, but inside `ShowLog` the AngularJS does not work. Why?

[image]

Can any one help me to figure this out?

Comment: does the angular library included properly to the page?

Comment: yes..Refer to the code above

Comment: put your script tags from the partial view into the main page or do something like this http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2010/11/12/execute-javascript-in-mvc-partial-view.aspx

Comment: Dear @himadri did you got your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Partial View does not trigger (Angular) Script. Meaning any angular call/execution using partial view doesn't registered at all.

The solution is either;

- Use [Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- Use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) instead of Ajax or @Html.Render

sample of using ngInclude:

```
<div ng-include="showlog"></div>
<div id="WorkArea"></div>
```

also, load your angular libraries in the header